# Best practice for adding Azure Application Insights to multiple .net apps

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

We are going to start adding Application Insights to a bunch of our web apps (20-30 apps). We have already done this on a few but wanted to get some feed back on the best approach.

Should we do 1 application insights and 1 log analytics workspace per app?

Can apps share log analytic workspaces and does this make querying logs easier?

Is there any documentation on this exact scenario?

Answer (score -1):

The only official document I found that mentions something along those lines is the consideration of [using Microsoft Sentinel with your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#workspaces-with-microsoft-sentinel). But most importantly it seems to be cost - that was the main driver for us.

In our case, we originally started with multiple Log Analytics Workspaces (LAW) for different types of applications and eventually moved to a centralised LAW as the log collection started to grow. You'd want to have multiple LAWs if you have different isolated teams/business units managing different sets of Web Apps. Cross-workspace queries exists to allow you to query across different workspaces.

However, the downside with multiple LAWs is that it brings about some management overhead, and can often cause confusion within the team if no proper naming convention exists.

You could settle for a single LAW if you have a single team managing this part of the environment. It's definitely possible to have multiple resources dump all their logs to a single LAW. The advantage here is it helps budgeting and planning purposes as once you hit the quota of 100GB worth of logs per day, you start getting discounts.

You might not even be hitting a fraction of this per day right now but when you're setting up stuff like this to be future-proof, you'd want to think very long term and have a very well-thought-of foundation.

Also, make sure you have a look at the LAW pricing for different regions - some are much cheaper than others and if there's no compliance/data residency requirements for your use case (other types of logs you might want to collect later), you could set up the LAW in the cheaper region. e.g. Per GB pricing in US can be close to 50% the cost in Asia. We ended up doing a big migration which saved us a ton!

Comment: Thanks Ked,   I was thinking along the lines of a single log analytics workspace.  We do have a large number of apps so perhaps there is some way to break this up into related LAWs but still keep it down to 2 or 3.

Do you still find with a single LAW that queries and reports can be generated for the different apps with no issues?

Comment: Definitely, it's just a matter of using the right query to filter out the apps you want. That's exactly what we use, although we have a many more complex use cases with automated actions based on logic apps that would query the workspace.

Comment: If the above has helped you, please mark it as answer so it can be closed. Else if you've found the answer on your own, you can post it and mark accordingly.